react-native-image-picker is not visible in android 14
I am using react-native-image-picker to pick images from gallery..it is working fine in most android devices.But in android 14 when i invoke launcImageLibrary() it shows a blank screen and if touch at any place of the blank screen an image is selected..
I tried using

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VISUAL_USER_SELECTED" />
but when i click allow all it again shows an blank page respectively

